# Get the name of the SAS program being run

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Are there any generic suggestions for identifying the SAS code / program that is being executed?

My code will execute within a generic macro, so could be called within a Stored Process, another macro, a client SAS program, or even SAS code generated via the mid-tier using IOM.  I'd like the highest level identifier possible..  (something that will return the same result if the same program is run again - so process id would not be helpful).

The environment is not windows, so this code is not helpful:

```
%put %sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME);
```

Also, the macro is not necessarily the first program that is called (if it is even a program) - so neither is this code helpful:

```
proc sql noprint;
select xpath into :progname
from sashelp.vextfl where upcase(xpath) like '%.SAS';
%put &progname;
```

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the information?

Comment: The info will be used to name the mfile (resolved) code to be stored in a separate location.  Is not a big issue as I can just use a timestamp, it would just be nice if this info was available!

Comment: This question has been around for a while I believe.. It may be that there is no answer / it is not possible to determine, as the code being executed has never been saved - so doesn't really 'exist' !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you may need to think through how this is to be be used a little more.  What if the same user has two sessions open running the same code?  Should that use the same file name?

Can you simply make it a requirement of your piece of code that a certain variable must have been specified before your code will run?  Otherwise return an error / abort further processing?

To answer your original question though I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I agree. Require a parameter to the macro that will be used to store the file...or like the question mentioned, a timestamp

Comment: accepted.  We have no control over what code calls the macro, so a parameter is not possible. A combination of user id / session id and timestamp has to be the way forward!  Thanks.